# R: rvest - getting nested text with rvest

Tags: r, rvest

Problem:

Extract the URL of the image of the product from this web:

```
http://www.linio.com.pe/computacion/pc-escritorio/
```

Some images have an attribute "data-origin", and i can pull the url of the images. The problem is, some products don't have this attribute. But they have the URL that i need in the src attribute.

So far:

1) I can get the url for products that have the attribute "data-origin".
2) Cannot get the url when products dont have the attribute "data-origin" but have the url in the src attribute.

#

Considerations:

There are two urls in the source code: with and without .*sprite.*.
I don't need the url with the sprite part.

Example for 1 product:

Rigth URL: `http://media.linio.com.pe/p/hp-1987-043329-1-catalog.jpg`

**This can be found in the img tag, or in the noscript part.**

Wrong URL: `http://media.linio.com.pe/p/hp-1987-043329-sprite.jpg`

**This is in the class "sprite-hidden"**

**UPDATE 1:**

Using SelectorGadget it says i should use ".lazyImg". But i don't get what i expect.

```
  PCimgs  <- html("http://www.linio.com.pe/computacion/pc-escritorio/")%>%
            html_nodes(".lazyImg")%>%
            html_text()
```

But i get:

```
[1] "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Investigating i see someone can use two html_nodes, one after the other.
This is more close to what i want. Because i need to get the url mentionated for all the products on the page.

```
PCs <- html("http://www.linio.com.pe/computacion/pc-escritorio/")%>%
    html_nodes(".product-item-img") %>%
    html_nodes("img")
```

But, this gives me more information than needed. So i've tried this modification (Thanks to user for this idea):

```
PCs <- html("http://www.linio.com.pe/computacion/pc-escritorio/")%>%
    html_nodes(".product-item-img") %>%
    html_nodes("img") %>%
    html_attr("data-original")
```

And this works!!! Partially:

I get:

```
 [1] "http://media.linio.com.pe/p/hp-1987-043329-1-catalog.jpg"      
 [2] NA                                                              
 [3] "http://media.linio.com.pe/p/hp-7585-499619-1-catalog.jpg"      
 [4] NA
```

This is because some elements have the attribute: data-origin, while others don't. But they have the url that i need in the scr attrbute. So i use:

```
PCs <- html("http://www.linio.com.pe/computacion/pc-escritorio/")%>%
    html_nodes(".product-item-img") %>%
    html_nodes("img") %>%
    html_attr("scr")
```

but i get:

```
> PCs
```

[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[33] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

Any help?

#

This is the source code from the page (http://www.linio.com.pe/computacion/pc-escritorio/)

```html
        <ul class="product-items" id="catalog-items">
              <li id="HP016EL59NXCPEAMZ" class="product-item " itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" data-badge="badgeDivFalse">
            <a id="1:HP016EL59NXCPEAMZ" href="http://www.linio.com.pe/HP---Desktop-All-in-One-Intel-Celeron-18.5-500GB-4GB---Plateado-Negro-923340.html" title="HP - Desktop All-in-One Intel Celeron 18.5'' 500GB 4GB - Plateado/Negro">
        <ul>
            <li class="product-item-img" style="position: relative;">
                <span class="lazyImage">
                    <span style="width:160px;height:160px;" class="itm-imageWrapper itm-imageWrapper-HP016EL59NXCPEAMZ">
                        <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVQYV2NgYAAAAAMAAWgmWQ0AAAAASUVORK5CYII="
                            data-original="http://media.linio.com.pe/p/hp-1987-043329-1-catalog.jpg"
                            width="160"
                            height="160" class="itm-img lazyImg"
                            onerror="catalog.onError($(this)); this.width=160">

                        <noscript>
                            <img
                                src="http://media.linio.com.pe/p/hp-1987-043329-1-catalog.jpg"
                                class="itm-img"
                                width="160"
                                height="160"
                            >
                        </noscript>
                                                </span>
                                                <span class="sprite hidden">http://media.linio.com.pe/p/hp-1987-043329-sprite.jpg</span>
                                        </span>
                                </li>
```

Comment: The problem here is the html_attr("scr") it should be: html_attr("src"). I've fixed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer for the question:

PCs will give you the information of the image section of the code. In the line 3 you can be more specific and use "img" to get the exact information.

```
PCs <- html("http://www.linio.com.pe/computacion/pc-escritorio/")%>%
    html_nodes(".product-item-img") %>%
    html_nodes("img")
```

**You'll notice that some elements have the url you want in the "data-original" attribut. While other's will have it in the "src" attribute.**

Example "data-original":

```
[[47]]
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVQYV2NgYAAAAAMAAWgmWQ0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" data-original="http://media.linio.com.pe/p/epson-9425-1474711-1-catalog.jpg" width="160" height="160" class="itm-img lazyImg" onerror="catalog.onError($(this)); this.width=160"/>
```

Example "src":

```
 [[46]]
<img src="http://media.linio.com.pe/p/lg-6587-168029-1-catalog.jpg" class="itm-img" width="160" height="160"/>
```

1 ) Use this code to get the url for the elements with the information in the "src" attribute.

```
   PCs2 <- html("http://www.linio.com.pe/computacion/pc-escritorio/")%>%
            html_nodes(".product-item-img") %>%
            html_nodes("img") %>%
            html_attr("src")
```

2 ) Use this code to get the url for the elements with the information in the "data-original" attribute.

```
PCs3 <- html("http://www.linio.com.pe/computacion/pc-escritorio/")%>%
        html_nodes(".product-item-img") %>%
        html_nodes("img") %>%
        html_attr("data-original")
```

**The problem continue, as i need a if else statement to determine where to use the "data-original" attr or the "src" attribbut. I'll make a new question for this.**

Answer (score 3):

```
    PCs <- html("http://www.linio.com.pe/computacion/pc-escritorio/")%>%
    html_node("span.itm-imageWrapper.itm-imageWrapper-HP016EL59NXCPEAMZ img")%>%
    html_attr("data-original")
[1] "http://media.linio.com.pe/p/hp-1987-043329-1-catalog.jpg"
```

Comment: You are right. I think i'm gonna do that, and then use some text manipulation to get what i need. 

I've used html_nodes() to get the info for all elements. However the object is in class: XMLNodeSet. I think i need to convert it to a list, in order to use a lapply function on it? (to remove the extra text that i don't need?)

Comment: I know, but your input has helped me to model the question in the right way. Thanks. I don't think it is necesary to open a new question.

Comment: Fair enough. If you are trying to get only links, you can use `getHTMLLinks("website")` from `library(XML)`.

Comment: I've tried that and that is not what im looking. Also, i would prefer to do this with rvest. I'll open a new question i guess.